# Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

Почему перед "и" во втором предложении ниже стоит запятая? Нужна ли она? Отрывок взят из учебника по патологии.

> В течение всей жизни человек приспосабливается (адаптируется) к условиям среды. В изменившихся условиях, при заболевании возникает нарушение нормальных функций, **и** в организме происходят компенсаторно-приспособительные реакции, направленные на восстановление нарушенных функций.

Мое предположение: если это не ошибка и запятая действительно нужна, я думаю, это потому, что событие во второй части предложения происходит после события в первой части. Однако у Розенталя я нашел такой [пример](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133):

> В это время тягуче скрипнула дверь сеновала **и** наружу просунулась голова деда Щукаря.

На мой взгляд, этот пример тоже описывает следующие друг за другом действия.
Почему в нем запятой нет, а в предложении из учебника есть?

Comment: @shampar  По поводу правки. Думаю, что основной вопрос связан с предложением из медучебника, а там как раз есть запятая. И автор вопроса ссылается на пример Розенталя, где ее нет.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Верно.

Comment: Ну так задайте себе труд выносить вопрос в шапку.  Втискивать туда немереную цитату, и только её, не делая намёка на проблему, неверно.

Comment: @shampar Немного исправил пост.

Comment: Я Вам предлагаю такую нейтральную и короткую шапку: _Нужна ли запятая перед союзом «и»?_ А также добавить метку — просто **и**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое предложение действительно [есть](http://www.medcollegelib.ru/doc/ISBN9785970419915-0008/-esf2k2z11-tabrel-mode-pgs.html).
Думаю, что запятая перед "и" нужна. Сначала "**возникает нарушение** нормальных функций" (когда? — *в изменившихся условиях, при заболевании*), и только **потом** (вследствие нарушения, из-за нарушения) **происходят реакции**, восстанавливающие эти функции.
Жирным выделены подлежащие и сказуемые — для них однородные обстоятельства (второстепенные члены), стоящие в начале предложения, не являются общими.

***В это время** тягуче скрипнула дверь сеновала и наружу просунулась голова деда Щукаря* (М. Шолохов. Поднятая целина).

В словаре Ефремовой:
**в это время**, *наречие*
В определенный момент в настоящее время (одновременно с каким-либо другим действием).

Обе части сложносочиненного предложения объединены этим второстепенным членом: **одновременно** (в то же самое время, тем часом, одномоментно) и дверь скрипела, и голова Щукаря просовывалась.
Сравните (с запятой):
[Сначала, поначалу, сперва] *Тягуче скрипнула дверь сеновала, **и*** [после, затем, через некоторое время] *наружу просунулась голова деда Щукаря.*

Comment: _В изменившихся условиях, при заболевании..._ Здесь нужна запятая?

Comment: Я думаю, что нужна: оба _однородных_ обстоятельства отвечают на один и тот же вопрос "когда?".